# How can I fail tests in a "teardown" fixture properly in pytest?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I have a test framework that is performing multiple asserts and catching them (inherited someone else's code). The proprietary results report is correct, but as you may have guessed, pytest will mark these as passed:

```
test_something.py::TestSomething::test_that_should_fail PASSED
```

I've added an autouse fixture as such:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def run_after_tests(self):
    yield
    if self.actually_failed():
        pytest.fail("Yay, failing when failures occur is cool!")
```

This solution works okay, except that it seems like the clean up happens after the test has already been marked as PASSED and a duplicate test is shown with an error.

Now pytest results look like this:

```
test_something.py::TestSomething::test_that_should_fail PASSED
test_something.py::TestSomething::test_that_should_fail ERROR
```

Is there a way to delay the evaluation of the test so it doesn't say it has passed?

I know this is a really stupid way of doing things and performing test evaluation at cleanup is not recommended, but there are too many tests that have been written this way and spending weeks to refactor the test is not feasible.

An alternative solution I've thought of is to write a decorator and then `sed` all the test cases and add it to the functions; but this is going to be my plan B if fixtures can't solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, a fixture is a separate object from the test itself.

You'll need to modify the appropriate pytest hook. I haven't personally tested, but I believe placing the following code into your projects `conftest.py` will give you your desired result.

```
def check_for_failure(output) -> bool:
    # define me

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    output = yield

    if check_for_failure(output):  
        pytest.fail()
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a much better solution and resolved my issues.